# What is the "reference system"?

Tags: ios, uicollisionbehavior

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollisionbehavior/1624826-translatesreferenceboundsintobou) for the iOS instance property `UICollisionBehavior translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary` has the description

> "Specifies whether a boundary based on the reference system is active."

What is the reference system?  I don't understand what the bounds are in relation to - but I think if I knew what they mean by "reference system" was, I might.

Comment: Check out the [overview](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidynamicanimator) for UIDynamicAnimator.  See if reading that helps explain what's going on.